# Next.js 13v use-client on server page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

In version 13 of Next, through the app folder, I don't understand yet how to use 'use-client' components, for example forms, on a page with server-only. It used to be much easier somehow

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns

I've tried it in different ways and through dynamic imports I don't understand how it should be implemented correctly

**I have a client component:**

```
export function NewsFeed({ }) {

    const [el, setEl] = useState(4);

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleResize() {
            if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
                setEl(2);
            }if (window.innerWidth < 640) {
                setEl(1);
            }else {
                setEl(4);
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        handleResize();
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, [])


    //generation  NewsFooter
    const generateIconsAndText = (count: number) => {
        const elements = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (i < 3) {
                elements.push(
                    <svg key={`svg-${i}`} width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    </svg>,
                    <span key={`span-${i}`} className={styles.footertTitle}>ОЧЕНЬ ВАЖНАЯ НОВОСТЬ</span>
                );
            } if (i == 3) {
                elements.push(
                    <svg key={`svg-${i}`} width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    </svg>,
                );
            }
        }

        return elements;
    }

    const NewsFooter = () => {
        return (
            <div className={styles.footer}>
                {generateIconsAndText(el)} 
            </div>
        );
    }


    return <div className={styles.background}>
        <div className={styles.title}>Лента</div>
        <div className={styles.content}>
            <ul>
                {firedNewsArr.map((item, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>
                        <div className={styles.newsLiDiv}>
                            <div className={styles.column}>
                                <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                            <div className={styles.column}>
                                <div className={styles.newsDesc}> {item.title}</div>
                                <div className={styles.newsAbout}>
                                    <div className={styles.newsTime}> {item.createdAt}</div>
                                    {/* <Btn props ={item.newsType} color={'#FF6B00'}/> */}

                                    <button className={styles.newsType}> {item.newsType} </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                ))}

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.footer}>
            <NewsFooter />
        </div>
    </div >
}
```

**When I import it into the server component I get an error:**

```
const NewsFeed = dynamic(() => import('./newsFeed/NewsFeed'), { ssr: false });

export function RightNewsBlock({ }) { <NewsFeed />}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63tbD.png)